# Converting model class to XML

Tags: xml, vb.net, class, models

I have the next classes in vb.net:

```vb
Class A 
    Public Property Bs As New List(Of B)
End Class

Class B
    Public Property D As String
    Public Property E As String
End class
```

I wish to convert them in xml using next code:

```vb
Dim sw1 = New StringWriter()
Dim xs1 As New XmlSerializer(A.GetType)
xs1.Serialize(New XmlTextWriter(sw1), A)
xml = xml.Replace("{1}", sw1.ToString())
```

The format of that classes will be:

```
<A>
  <Bs>
    <B>
      <D>1</D>
      <E>2</E>
    </B>
    <B>
      <D>3</D>
      <E>2</E>
    </B>
</Bs>
</A>
```

But I would wish to have next one:

```
<A>
    <B>
      <D>1</D>
      <E>2</E>
    </B>
    <B>
      <D>3</D>
      <E>2</E>
    </B>
</A>
```

Without tag Bs, how can I do it using  XmlElement or XArray... in the class?

Comment: When serializing class `A` to XML, do you need to include other properties in it as well or just the `List(Of B)`?

Comment: yes all elements inside B

Comment: do you refer all properties inside Bs?

Comment: Oh, well I meant do you need any other properties/fields from _class A_? Because if you have no other properties inside `A`, or if you don't care about them, I don't see why you just don't serialize the list itself instead of the whole class `A`.

Comment: oh yes i have to mantain them, I missunderstood all properties inside A and B

Comment: Glad I could help! It was by "accident" I found out the answer. I was just trying out different things to see if anything worked. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this behaviour by applying the [**`XmlElement` attribute**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to your list, ignoring `XmlArray` and `XmlArrayItem`:

```vb
Class A
    <XmlElement("B")> _
    Public Property Bs As New List(Of B)
End Class
```